# How To Control Looping HTML Table PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach

So, i've table like in picture 
[image]

I want put looping row person on left side to singgle row select box on right side, like by color. And this is a code table right side.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>No.</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>

  <?php if(!empty($query)) { $number=1 ; foreach($query as $row) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <?php echo $number++ ?>.</td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $row->column_a ?></td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $row->column_b ?></td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $row->column_c ?></td>

  </tr>
  <?php }} ?>
</table>
```

How to control looping iteration, to make this is happen?
Tanks a lot.

Comment: .... What? You might want to get a more fluent english speaking friend to translate your question, it's hard to understand.

Comment: what do you want to show in select box under column A?

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu i want to show (Alan, Benji, Charli) (Ivan, Johny, Doris) (Benji, Edward, Fiora) in single row. Help me !!

Comment: what is the logic? I mean if name start with 'Alan', then show the whole row inside 1st selectbox?

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu Its like grouping 3 row at left table, to show in single row at right table (each select box).

Comment: @Epodax I apologize !

Comment: No need to apologize @KholiqFadli I'm very well aware that English isn't everyone's mother language, it certainly isn't mine.

Comment: From where you got the data to show this tabular format as per pic 1?

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu i want show from same data ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend just help to fix my problem,

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>No.</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>

  <?php if(!empty($query)) { $number=1;$count=0; foreach($query as $row) { ?>
<?php if($count % 3 == 0){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <?php echo $number++ ?>.</td>
<?php } ?>
    <td>
      <?php echo $row->column_a ?></td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $row->column_b ?></td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $row->column_c ?></td>
<?php $count++; if($count % 3 == 0){ ?>
  </tr>

  <?php }}} ?>
</table>
```